# How to create a new column in a CSV file using existing data and then use it as a key to to print a sorted list

Tags: python, csv

For an assignment I need to produce a list of bets in date order from a CSV file. The file is as below (sample):

```
Aintree, Red Rum,2017,5,12,11.58, won
Aintree, Hurricane Fly,2017,5,12,11.58, won
Aintree, Murder,2017,5,12,5, lost
Ayr, Corbiere,2016,11,3,25, lost
```

I would like to create a new column for each row combining `[2],[3],[4]` in format `'%d-%b-%y'` within the CSV. I then need to use this new column as the key to produce a list of bets `[5]` in date order.

I have this code below, being new to python I have not had much success and not sure where it is going wrong. It produces this error when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date_bet.py", line 25, in <module>
    get_date()
  File "date_bet.py", line 10, in get_date
    data = list(csv.reader(csvFile))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def get_date():
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)

        all = []
        data = list(csv.reader(csvFile))
        row = next(csvFile)
        row.append([7])
        all.append(row)

    for row in data:
        row.append((data[4],data[3],data[2]), '%d-%b-%y')
        all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)


    date = datetime.date(row[7], '%x')
    print(row[5], key = date)

get_date()
```

Comment: You do not appear to be calling your `get_date` function.

Comment: Sorry that was a stupid error. When I call I get this error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date_bet.py", line 25, in <module>
    get_date()
  File "date_bet.py", line 10, in get_date
    data = list(csv.reader(csvFile))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Jack: Please put the traceback *in* your question (and add the missing call to `get_date()`).

Comment: You're opening your file in mode `'a'` (which is not a read mode), and then trying to read from it.

Comment: If I open in mode 'r' do I need to create a of the csv through mode 'w' then to create the new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) to achieve what you want.

> I would like to create a new column for each row combining [2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html),[3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html),[4] in format '%d-%b-%y'

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(<your_file_name>, header=None)
```

Add the column using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df[2], month=df[3], day=df[4]), format='%d-%b-%y')
df

    0           1                2      3   4   5       6           date
0   Aintree     Red Rum         2017    5   12  11.58   won     2017-05-12
1   Aintree     Hurricane Fly   2017    5   12  11.58   won     2017-05-12
2   Aintree     Murder          2017    5   12  5.00    lost    2017-05-12
3   Ayr         Corbiere        2016    11  3   25.00   lost    2016-11-03
```

> I then need to use this new column as the key to produce a list of bets [5] in date order.

```
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
print(df[[5, 'date']].reset_index(drop=True)) # reset index so that you don't see the mixedup index.

       5       date
0  25.00 2016-11-03
1  11.58 2017-05-12
2  11.58 2017-05-12
3   5.00 2017-05-12
```

---

You can save this to a csv using [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

Comment: Thank you very much that's very helpful. I voted on your answer but it says my reputation is too low to publicly change it.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas. Adding new column named 'date' and sorting the data by the new column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('55611308.csv', sep=',', names=['name0', 'name1', 'y', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'result'], header=None)
df['date'] = df['y'].astype(str).str.cat(df['m'].astype(str), sep='-').str.cat(df['d'].astype(str), sep='-')
df.sort_values('date',inplace=True)

print(df)
```